# How to refresh multiples screens later to click logout in only one Screen with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I have an web application that the user open multiples tabs or windows, and I have a requirement whenever the user click the logout link in one of the open windows or tabs, must be closed all the screens opened with the same session. So I was wondering something like using `HttpSessionListener` to capture the session and to refresh the screen if the current session is invalidate, but I don't know if that is the best approach to do it... I m using Spring security do to the Authentication process.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you pass in the SessionStatus into your login method, assuming its a method on the Controller, and call setComplete()?  That should invalidate the session, which would, in theory, invalidate all the logins associated with the other tabs.  Otherwise, you may have to devise some complicated messaging scheme.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add some Ajax polling to your pages that would detect session invalidation (Ajax request returning HTTP 401 for example).

But closing the tabs/windows when that happens, probably not so nice for user experience.

What you could do instead is to render a modal notification dialog on the page (tab) when it detects logout. I believe Google uses this type of approach in e.g. Drive.